# setTitle for UIButton results in it disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have changed the alpha of the button successfully so I know I can modify it. But when I use setTitle, the button just disappears.

I have a tableview with collection views in each cell. I have a custom header cell that when tapped, presents options including the button that disappears when tapping on it.

Here is the function in the main view controller that is called properly and works (I know because I can change the alpha of the button and even make it hidden).

```
func deleteScenes(){
    if let header = whichHeaderTapped {
        header.deleteScenesOutlet.setTitle("fuckssake", for: .normal)
        header.deleteActOutlet.alpha = 0.0
        header.editButtonOutlet.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

Here is the class for the header cell.

```
class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

static var shared = HeaderCell()

@IBOutlet var headerName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var newOptions: UIStackView!

@IBOutlet var deleteScenesOutlet: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var deleteActOutlet: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var editButtonOutlet: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.newOptions.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 285, y: 0)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}

@IBAction func deleteScenesButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if deleteScenesOutlet.titleLabel?.text == "Delete Scenes" {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "deleteScenesButtonEnabled"), object: nil)
    }

    else {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "deleteScenesButtonDisabled"), object: nil)
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Check the wiring in storyboard and make sure you haven't connected the wrong buttons. Also useful to open the view hierarchy and inspect the elements position and size

Comment: If you set alpha 0 you are never going to see the button.set alpha 1 to make it visible

Comment: the buttons I set alpha to 0 are the buttons I want to disappear. the deletesceneoutlet button is the one I'm trying to change the title of and yet it disappears. I've tried manually setting its own alpha to 1.0. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. Can you check what is the color of your button title. If it is white and your background view color is also white then there is a chance you were not able to see the button.

Comment: good idea but no, I changed the bg color and it still doesn't show. thing is, the text color of the button is good from the start, I don't see why setting the title to something else would change the color.